# Proof of a two-dimensional random variable

Tags: probability

A two-dimensional random variable $ (X,Y) $ has total probability density function like $ f _{X,Y} (x,y) $.

And I want to prove that probability density function of a random variable $Z=X+Y$
is $f_{Z}(z) = \int_{- \infty }^{ \infty } f _{X,Y} (x, z-x)dx$ .

And I don't know how to do it? Any help.

Comment: Start with $P[Z \leq z] =...$ and differentiate with respect to $z$.  You can either do a 2-d integral to compute $P[Z\leq z]$, or teh law of total probability.

Comment: Apply Fubini's Theorem.